# Delete the row after removing file from storage

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

everything works perfectly but it throw an error “Trying to get
property ‘path’ of non-object” on this line
**“unlink(“uploads/”.$img->path);”** and when I refresh the row and file
are deleted .if there is another way please tell me

blade :

```
<table class="table table-hover">

  <thead>

    <tr>

     <th scope="col">image</th>
     <th scope="col">title</th>
     <th scope="col">Actions </th>
     </tr>

     </thead>



        <tbody>

  @foreach($data as $img)

<tr>

<th scope="row"> <img src="uploads/{{ $img->path }}" width="50%" /></th>

  <td>{{$img->title}}</td>
   <td>

  <a href='#'><i class="fa fa-edit"    id="updateIcon"   wire:click="selectItem({{ $img->id }}, 'update')" ></i></a>

  &nbsp;&nbsp;

  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash" style='color:red;'    wire:click="selectItem({{ $img->id }}, 'delete')"  data-target="#modalFormDelete"></i></a>

  </td>

    @endforeach

</tr>
```

class:

```
   public function selectItem($itemId, $action)
    {
        $this->selectedItem = $itemId;
        if ($action == 'delete') {
             $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('openDeleteModal');
        }
        
        
    }
    public function delete()
    {
        $img=Caroussel_Img::find($this->selectedItem);
        unlink("uploads/".$img->path);//bug here
        Caroussel_Img::where("id",$img->id)->delete();
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('closeDeleteModal');
     }
```

Comment: The selected item doesn't exist, as per your error message, and you don't handle the case for when it doesn't. You should also consider adding authorization to ensure the user is allowed to delete that image.

Comment: You should also key any elements that are generated in a loop to make sure Livewire always knows what's what

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not a good idea,
and I don't know what is inside "Caroussel_Img"

But if it is removing the file add "@" at beginning of the line and it won't bother you anymore

`@unlink("uploads/".$img->path);`

Comment: Suppressing errors rather than handling them is a very bad idea.

Comment: I said it's a bad idea without knowing what's inside that class!